# Effective equidistribution

Tags: ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation

I have an irrational number $\alpha$ (in this case, $\alpha=1/(2\pi)$, but hopefully answers will be more general) and I am interested in finding bounds on the size of
$$
T=\{k: k\alpha-\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor \in I\}
$$

for some interval $I\in[0,1)$. (Actually, I think it would be more natural to take intervals of $S^1$, or finite unions of same, but this is sufficient for my purposes.)

By the equidistribution theorem we know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|T\cap\{1,2,\ldots\}|}{n}=\ell
$$
where $\ell$ is the length of the interval $I$. But I would like to know more about the error term
$$
E_n=|T\cap\{1,2,\ldots\}|-\ell n.
$$

Comment: This is an extremely challenging question... A result of Kesten (1960-1962) asserts that, *after averaging on $\alpha$*, the discrepancy is of the order of $\ln (n)$. I suspect that, for quadratic irrationals, the discrepancy is of the order of $\sqrt{\ln(n)}$. There are lot of results and conjectures for specific cases, and I guess that none apply explicitly to $(2\pi)^{-1}$. Keywords : discrepancy, irrational rotations.

Comment: Sequence you presented is equidistributed, There are many different equivalent definitions of equidistributions. One of them is probability based. If we pick randomly (with linearly equidistributed probability) point on the $[0,1]$ chances that it is in $I$ equal to the length of $I$. Therefore $lim_{n \to \inf} E_n$ does not exists.

Comment: @hOff I know $\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n$ doesn't exist. The equidistribution theorem says that $E_n=o(n)$ and I'd like to know if that can be improved to, say, $E_n=O(\sqrt n)$. I'm interested in results in either direction: examples of $E_n$ which are larger than some $f(n)$ infinitely often and bounds with $E_n \ll g(n)$.

Comment: From an answer I gave on mathoverflow some time ago, you cannot do better than $o(n)$ in general. http://mathoverflow.net/a/42011

Comment: @GeorgeLowther: That is fantastic, exactly what I was looking for! Feel free to create an answer pointing there if you want the bounty.

Comment: Missed the bounty, but I posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to put a bound better than $o(n)$ for arbitrary irrational $\alpha$. More precisely, if $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is any function with $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(n)/n=0$ then there exists uncountably many irrational $\alpha$ with $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert E_n\rvert/f(n)=\infty$. See my [answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/42011).

However, for specific $\alpha$ it is possible to do better. As shown in the answer linked above, we have $E_n=o(n^x)$ for any $x > 1/2$ so long as $\alpha$ has [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) 2, and [almost every](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) real number has irrationality measure 2. It is an unsolved problem as to whether $\pi$ (and, equivalently, $1/(2\pi)$) has irrationality measure 2, but it is expected that it does.