# Effective equidistribution for number with bounded irrationality measure

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation, equidistribution

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949911/effective-equidistribution) asked for  bounds greater than $\omicron\left(n\right)$ on the error
$$
E_n=|T\cap\{1,2,\ldots\}|-\ell n.
$$
where
$$
\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|T\cap\{1,2,\ldots\}|}{n} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad T=\{k: k\alpha-\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor \in I\}$$
and $\alpha$ is an arbitrary irrational number. The question was answered in negative for such an arbitrary $\alpha$, but in positive under the additional hypothesis that the number has irrationality measure equals to $2$.

I would be very interested in knowing if there are similar results for numbers with irrationality measure $\le m$ where $m$ is greater than $2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. $T$ is in the interval, how can it have a non empty intersection with natural numbers?

Comment: Maybe the notation it is not the clearest one, but I preferred to mantain the same of original post. Anyway, I believe that $T$ is not in the interval, it is the set of $k$ s.t. $k\alpha-[k\alpha]$ is in the interval. So the intersection with natural numbers is just a way to say we are considering integer multiples of $\alpha$.

Comment: How right, I understand now. Good question

Comment: Look at the book "uniform distribution of sequences" by Kuipers and Niederreiter.